# Trying to target result in JSON with JQUERY but I'm doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to target the "workdmark" result and the "description" result in the following JSON

```
{
"count": 1,
"trademarks": [{
    "serialnumber": "85726321",
    "wordmark": "RAIR",
    "code": "GS0351",
    "description": "Regulatory driver log audit reporting and vehicle accident 
     registry for the transportation industry",
    "registrationdate": "06/25/2013"
}]
}
```

currently if I'm passing in "result", and I log

```
console.log(`${result.count}`);
```

I get 1 which is correct.

but if I

```
console.log(`${result.count}`);
console.log(`${result.trademarks}`);
console.log(`${result.trademarks.wordmark}`);
console.log(`${result.trademarks.description}`);
```

I get

```
1
[object object]
undefined
undefined
```

I thought I was targeting them correctly? What am I screwing up?

Comment: `result.trademarks` is an array.

Comment: If you try ${result.trademarks[0]} then it should work.

Comment: Try `${result.trademarks[1]}`

Comment: @AhmetZeybek arrays are not indexed from 1 but 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get values as below

```
console.log(`${result.trademarks[0].wordmark}`);
console.log(`${result.trademarks[0].description}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the structure of the trademark, basically it is an object in an array. So when you deal with these type of structure you should treat it as you are accessing an array and reference the index position first. Once you reference the index position you can then again use the object notation. So ideally you should do something like `result.trademarks[0].wordmark` and you would get `RAIR`.